# Flexible jni project

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

It seems like that working with jni will become my everyday routine for a few months. Is there any some tools which simplify dealing with mixed Java + C++ projects?

Is it possible to re-generate glue *.h files and rebuild native libraries automatically? Or I should write some scripts for maven, ant, gradle, anything_else? 
Is there any experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some months ago I faced the same questions.  It seems that Java/C++ interop is reviving just now, and that you are one of the pioneers.

If you're merely using C++ objects from Java, [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) may be a better solution.

If you're using Java from C++, I didn't yet encounter a mature library.  Although  functionally quite complete, **JNI is is a C api** (intentionally, if you read the design rationale).  If you are about to write lots of code for it, I think it'll pay to write a C++ framework around it that wraps the bare `jobject` ,`jnienv`, `jclass`... handles into explicit resources.

The real issues arise when the C++ and Java have to co-operate using callbacks etc...  Buckle up if that's your intent...

Comment: It's very intresting, cause I used to write some wrappers over jni for my purposes.. Does each jni-developer ends up with personal super-comfortable-jni-framework?

Comment: @AlexPovar: I'm actually hoping that 'someone' would start a project on github or so.  (If not, I promise to consider it myself:) )

Comment: If it really actual, one can create project on github with description and empty main() method and community do the rest =)

Comment: Guys, please do check JavaCPP and Jace already before writing any more of that nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/)! I also list other solutions on that page... There's also [Jace](http://code.google.com/p/jace/) that is useful when trying to use Java from C++.

Comment: It certainly does look very promising.  Do you have JavaCPP experience with bidirectional communication between objects living in the JVM and objects living natively?

Comment: @xtofl Sure, I'm doing it for JavaCV :) If you have specific examples of "bidirectional communication" you would like to achieve, please point me to the question and I will take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about an experience. So my experience is, that you should start with very well designed requirements, behavior and objects lifecycle. That should result in a mature interface which will change very little in the future. The effect is that you will need to change the glue header files rarely and simple one shot javah is good enough. It all doesn't sound very agile i know, but then JNI is everything but a rapid development environment.

Changing the interface twice a day, adding and removing methods and changing signatures "just to see if it helps" is a sure road to hell. You are connecting two very different worlds in terms of memory management and JVM can get nervous very easily. Thread safety is yet another level up. The mentioned helper solutions, while they are undoubtely a clever piece of software, might give you a false perception that JNI is easy. Then JVM starts giving you exceptions out of nowhere, your objects will start geting uninitalized randomly, etc...

Comment: Wow, is it really so bad? I have small experience with JNI in such manner like you said: with well designed interoperable interface and it was rather comfortable, because all I should do when add some functionality to native code is to press F11 in netbeans to rebuild it. But now situation is a bit different. I trying to find approach for that good interface design. So, I should do some experiments to choose proper way. Anyway, can you give some general advices on JNI?  Should I keep just a pieces of algorithm in native and rule with it from java? Or should I keep all specific logic in native?

Comment: I didn't say it's bad, i said it's not simple :) My general advice is to do in native only what you can't do in java. Every now and then, do a formal sanity check: look up every single heap object you are using and make sure that you know who and when is allocating and deallocating it. If your native code is leaking just a little bit, it might be practically tolerable if run as native. You might even not notice. But JVM has its own level of tolerance and will tell you in incomprehensible and unpleasant ways.

Comment: Ok, thank you for experience:) And is there any books to read about good practices or shortways with JNI? Or just everyday bug-fighting will bring experience?

Comment: I did away with the [downloadable Liang book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/). You might think it's stale (2002) but JNI doesn't change either. It helped me with everything i stumbled upon: thread safety, local/global refs, static initializers etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SWIG](http://swig.org) to automatically generate glue code and have an make target to rebuild the native libraries. You can also use ANT's c++ task for the same purpose.

Comment: I read a bit about SWIG and find it very intresting. But is it able to make callbacks to java?

Comment: It depends - but the answer is yes for the general case - see http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html paragraph 5.4.9.

Comment: Its intresting. If it really can do this SWIG will be the best solution. Have you got any experience with it?

Comment: I have barely touched callbacks via SWIG so my experience here is useless. I used SWIG mainly for wrapping platform library code. OTOH JNA solution is more straightforward in your case as it implies lesser overhead.